# getInt from sharedPreferences android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to use getInt to get an integer from my preferences so when the user selects a sport in the preferences it will set a different layout depending on which sport they pick

my java

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getPrefs.getInt("sports", 1)){

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }else if(getPrefs.getInt("sports", 1)){

        setContentView(R.layout.hockey);
    }else if(getPrefs.getInt("sports", 1)){


        setContentView(R.layout.basketball);
    }
```

my preference xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<ListPreference
    android:entries="@array/list"
    android:key="sports"
    android:summary="Choose your sport"
    android:title="Sports" 
    android:entryValues="@array/lValues"
    android:defaultValue="1">
</ListPreference>
```

my array xml

```
<string-array name="list">

     <item >
        Soccer
    </item>

    <item >
        Lacross
    </item>


    <item >
        Hockey
    </item>


    <item >
        VolleyBall
    </item>

    <item >
        Basketball
    </item>

    </string-array>



     <string-array name="lValues">
          <item >
         1
    </item>


    <item >
         2
    </item>


    <item >
         3
    </item>

    <item >
         4
    </item>
    <item>
        5
    </item>
         </string-array>
```

I get the error under

```
    getPrefs.getInt("sports", 1)
```

The minimum sdk and the target sdk are both 10 if that makes a difference.

Comment: on `(getPrefs.getInt("sports", 1))` it says **type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 is different from true.

1 is an int while true is a boolean.

I guess you should do:

```
if(getPrefs.getInt("sports", 1)==1)
```

or

```
if(getPrefs.getInt("sports", 1)==2)
```

BTW, in your case, i would do:

```
switch(getPrefs.getInt("sports", 1)){
    case 1:
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        break;
    case 2:
        setContentView(R.layout.hockey);
        break;
    //blahBlah
}
```